# CMake Error: Target contains relative path in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES

Tags: cmake, cgal, msys2

I mean to compile example `Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction` from the CGAL package under Win10 + PortableApps Msys2.
For the library itself I use a precompiled package (`$ pacman -Qs cgal` gives `local/mingw-w64-x86_64-cgal 4.14-1`).
I used to be able to do that in my previous PC, see details below.

After transferring everything to a new PC (simply copying, it is PortableApps), I made a system update in Msys2 (required for other reasons).
I proceed as usual: `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `ccmake ..`. Selecting `Release` mode, and verbosity `ON`, upon pressing `g` to generate files I got

```
 CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
   Imported target "CGAL::CGAL" includes non-existent path
     "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/include"
   in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:
   * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
   * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
   * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
   provide.
```

Upon pressing `e` to exit the error message, the `ccmake` gui was exited and there were no files generated.

After googling a bit, [this](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1175) suggested creating the *missing dirs*, which seems merely a workaround (I did not try adapting [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14323)).
I created those dirs, and then I got

```
 CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
   Target "CGAL::CGAL" contains relative path in its
   INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES:

     "C:/building/msys64/mingw64/include"
```

**How can I fix this?**
I found no suitable answers around.

Possibly related links, but which I found no way of relating to a suitable solution:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/634bb33f3aa3b7f2181a896c025976b52171524a

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

**NOTE**:
The same happened with other examples.

**EDIT**:
I do not know what changed, but now upon pressing `e` to exit the error message (see above) all generated files are present, including the `Makefile`.
So I can proceed as described below in *Previous state of affairs*.
This happens either with or without the *missing dirs* (the error message changes, but I can generate my executables).
AFAICT, the only related change is that
I have just installed packages 
, `mingw-w64-x86_64-eigen3 (3.3.7-1)`
, `mingw-w64-x86_64-suitesparse (5.4.0-1)`
, `mingw-w64-x86_64-lapack (3.8.0-5)`
, but I would not think this should matter.

---

*Previous state of affairs*

To compile and link CGAL examples, in my previous PC, some tweaking was needed. 
Compilation went fine, but linking required a couple of tweaks.
An example command line produced for linking reads

```
 /mingw64/bin/c++.exe -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/reconstruction_structured.dir/reconstruction_structured.cpp.o  -o reconstruction_structured.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libreconstruction_structured.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 /mingw64/lib/lib/libmpfr.a /mingw64/lib/lib/libgmp.dll.a /mingw64/lib/lib/libCGAL.dll.a -lC:/building/msys64/mingw64/lib/libgmp.dll.a -lC:/building/msys64/mingw64/lib/libmpfr.a
```

The two types of required fixes are

1. Replacing `/mingw64/lib/lib/` with `/mingw64/lib/` in every (`link.txt`;`build.make`) file.
2. Replacing  flag `-lC:/building/msys64/mingw64/lib/libgmp.dll.a` with `-lgmp` in every `link.txt` file. Similarly for `-lmpfr`.

Comment: Can you post a link to the source code you are trying to compile?  There is apparently some problem with the way it defines its `CGAL::CGAL` CMake target, so we should try to fix the CMake code that defines that target.

Comment: @DavidGrayson - `$ pacman -Qs cgal` gives `local/mingw-w64-x86_64-cgal 4.14-1`, and that would be https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-cgal

Comment: That's a precompiled, binary package made by the MSYS2 developers.  Are you trying to just use that, or are you trying to actually compile CGAL yourself as stated at the top of your question?

Comment: I am compiling/linking examples from CGAL. But for the library itself I use the precompiled package... Will fix the OP.

Comment: I gave my best attempt at an answer, but if you want more help you should really say exactly what source code you are compiling and what commands you are attempting to run when you compile it so that someone else could see the same error message on their screen without making a bunch of guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: @DavidGrayson - I expanded the description. Hopefully it is clear enough now.
Note: as edited, I can now compile/link, even in the presence of the errors.
I still think it may be worth clarifying the issue (with a different urgency), as the problem may show up again, for me or other users (I guess my configuration is a rare combination anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command to find all the places in the CGAL CMake files where the erroneous directory `C:/building/` is mentioned:

```
grep -r '/building/' /mingw64/lib/cmake/CGAL
```

For each instance, either delete it or replace it with something more appropriate.

(Note: I haven't tried this myself.)

This erroneous directory is a general issue with MSYS2 which I [attempted to fix at one point](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-pacman/pull/19).

Comment: This solved the problem indeed!
In addition, it led me to the place where to solve #2 of "The two types of required fixes..." in the OP.
I still have to find how to solve #1 to have a clean build procedure.
But I can work.